# Playing audio chunks received from api as a single audio without any break

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to stream an audio, I receive the chunks of octet-stream of audio as response from the api, and in the frontend i have to merge the chunks as i receive them and play the audio as one.

How can i merge them for smooth playing?

Trying to get this done in reactJS.

Comment: Don't try to merge them on frontend, JS isn't designed for such low level operations. Use a library like videojs to stream a HLS of the audio stream.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.